# get current month using chaining in momentjs failed

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
console.log(moment().month().format('M'))
```

Why I can't chain moment date object like this? Says this month is May I expect I got 5 but I got error of format is not a function.

Comment: Did you mean `moment().format('M')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
moment().format('M');//should work
```

This should work as `moment()` returns an object (a moment object) which has a method `format`.

```
moment().month().format('M');//will evaluate to 5.format()
```

`moment().month()` probably returns a Number, which doesn't have a method `format()` so it shows an error. it is like doing `5.format('M')`

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
moment().format('MMM'); //Output: May

moment().format('MM'); //Output: 05
```

month(); method is for getting/setting month. If `moment().month()` is used, it gives current month. If `moment().month(3)` is used, it sets the month.

```
NOTE: While setting month be aware that index starts from 0. 
i.e. If you do moment().month(3).format('MMM'); You will get "Apr" and not "Mar"
```

When you do `moment().month()` moment will return the number of the current month(index starting from 0). But when you set a month using `moment().month(3)` and then use `.format()` function it will work because `moment().month()` returns a moment object and hence has the `format()` method.